# How to add/remove a prefix string to the data using R?

Tags: r

I have a column `issueID`

Tt has some values

```
101, 102, 103, IS-104, IS-105, IS-106,
```

How can I use a R code to either remove all the "IS-" before IS-104, IS-105, IS106;  or find a way to add the "IS-" in front of  101, 102, 103?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `sub`, match the pattern of digits (`\\d+`)`at the start (`^`) of the string, capture (`(...)`) as a group and in the replacement, add the string "IS-" before the backreference of the captured group

```
sub("^(\\d+)", "IS-\\1", df1$issueID)
#[1] "IS-101" "IS-102" "IS-103" "IS-104" "IS-105" "IS-106"
```

---

Another option is to create an `ifelse` condition with `grepl` and then `paste` the elements that doesn't have 'IS" at the start of the string

```
with(df1, ifelse(grepl("^IS", issueID), issueID, paste0("ID-", issueID)))
```

#### data

```
df1 <- data.frame(issueID = c("101", "102", "103", "IS-104", "IS-105",
                 "IS-106"), stringsAsFactors = FALSE)
```

Comment: Hi @akrun, Thanks for your help; when I applied the second option the ifelse condition, for some reason the issueID that has IS- is removed.  my final result became (IS-101, IS-102, IS-103, 104,105,106) , may I know why this is happening?

Comment: @xiongbenxiong  Check whether you have `factor` column.  In the example dat I posted, it is `character` class.  So i am getting `[1] "ID-101" "ID-102" "ID-103" "IS-104" "IS-105" "IS-106"`  If I change `stringsAsFactors = TRUE` or the default case, it would be `factor` and the result would  be `[1] "ID-101" "ID-102" "ID-103" "4"      "5"      "6"` (from this example).  I would suggest to convert the xolumn to `character` xlass with `as.character(issueID)`

Comment: @ Hi Akrun, you are right! after convert to character , everything works fine ,  only a small doubt is I am only  adding "ID-", but an extra space is introduced to 101, 102, 102. Instead of having ID-101, I am getting "ID- (extra space) 101"

Comment: Could be that your original column have some leading/lagging spaces, try `trimws(as.character(issueID))`.